# Adding an image link or load

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, content-management-system

I'm editing my website and in my admin section I am creating a CMS.

In my ADD.PHP I have added a few fields. These fields work but today I decided to add an upload to the image field.

My ADD.PHP code is this:

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('../include/connection.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
      if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])) {
             $title = $_POST['title'];
             $content = nl2br($_POST['content']);
             $image = $_POST['image'];
             $link = $_POST['link'];
             $category = $_POST['category'];
             $brand = $_POST['brand'];

if (empty($title) or empty($content)) {
             $error = 'All Fields Are Required!';
}else{
     $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO mobi (promo_title, promo_content, promo_image, promo_link, promo_cat, promo_name) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
     $query->bindValue(1, $title);
     $query->bindValue(2, $content);
     $query->bindValue(3, $image);
     $query->bindValue(4, $link);
     $query->bindValue(5, $category);
     $query->bindValue(6, $brand);

     $query->execute();
    header('location: index.php');
}

}
          ?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Add Article</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../other.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<a href="index.php" id="logo"><b>&larr; Back</b></a>

<br />

<div align="center">
<h4>Add Article</h4>

<?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
     <small style="color:#aa0000;"><?php echo $error; ?></small><br /><br />
<?php } ?>

<form action="add.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" /><br /><br />
<textarea rows="15" cols="50" placeholder="Content" name="content"></textarea><br /><br />
<input name="image" type="file" id="image" />
<input type="text" name="image" placeholder="Image" /><br /><br />
<input type="link" name="link" placeholder="Link" /><br /><br />
<input type="category" name="category" placeholder="Category" /><br /><br />
<input type="category" name="brand" placeholder="Brand" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Add Article" />

</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>


<?php
}else{
       header('location: index.php');
}

?>
```

As you can see, I have a select box and then a text box both for the image.

What I would like is for one or the other to be added to the same field. So for example.

**If I have an image on my computer then I will select the file using the "choose file" button. But if I want to use a web image then I will enter it into the image box.**

But I want both options to add to the same promo_link database field.

I want only one to be selected.

How can I do this?

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest that if you are stuck here with your custom content management system that you not reinvent the wheel but use a framework or a CMS that is already out there and modify it to fit. If you really want to do this yourself then you have a lot of rough trails ahead.

Comment: I know it can be done by adding an or to this $query->bindValue(3, $image); I'm just not sure how that is all.

Comment: first of all your have to decide what element is going to trigger the `or`. then you can simply do an `if(trigger){/*insert image*/} else {/*insert link*/}` so the question is, what is the trigger or which one do you prefer in case that they are both filled in. the trigger could be something similiar to `empty(["image_url"])` because you cannot have two form elements with the same name unless you want one overwritten all the time.

Comment: I want the URL image to be the priority and the upload box as 2nd priority. This is for my use only not to be used by users.

Comment: `This is for my use only not to be used by users.` I have thought this same thing before only to later have to reuse the code or turn over a site to another administrator and then have to spend days explaining how things work that aren't self explanatory. Always plan on someone else seeing your code and someone else managing your site... ALWAYS! If you know which to be the priority then change the form element names and put in a if else condition in your php.

Comment: Where abouts do I enter it?

Comment: if you don't know where to enter it, then maybe you should follow my first comment while you are ahead... put it in your php code around `$image = $_POST['image'];` as the if and else statements. I also HIGHLY suggest this [book](http://www.amazon.com/How-Think-Like-Programmer-Bewildered/dp/1844809005)